# Generating models and migrations for an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-plugins

So I'm working on a new project that seems like a great choice for using the new Engine functionality. It's as engines say, its own little app, w/ its own views and controllers and models. Here's where I'm coming up short.

I create my test application in which I will mount the new engine.

```
rails new engine_app && cd engine_app
```

I then create the new engine

```
rails plugin new my_engine --mountable
```

I then add the 'gem' to the engine_app's gemfile

```
gem 'my_engine', :path => './my_engine'
```

I then mount the engine in engine_app's routes as so

```
mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => '/my_engine'
```

I then cd into my_engine's dummy app and run

```
rails generate model MyModel title:string body:text
```

Here's where I run into my confusion. From what I understand this is supposed to generate a namespace table (I think it would be my_engine_my_model). The table in the migration file is just my_model.

Secondly how do I run this migration and is the migration file correct in only calling the table :my_model? I have tried running the following but nothing seems to happen, and I've checked the database and the table isn't there.

So to recap, I need to know how to create migrations in the engine, and be able to run them on the parent apps database correctly.

Thanks for any help and guidance.

Answer (score 5):

So all of the tutorials I read didn't specify that you needed to run script/rails generate from within the root level of your engine. I kept seeing references telling me to goto the test/dummy app. After running script/rails generate model [fields] from the root of my engine it created the appropriate model, migration rake task and i was able to run

```
rake my_engine:install:migrations; rake db:migrate
```

to run the migrations

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generator with the engine target:

```
bin/engem ENGINE_NAME rails g GENERATOR
```